# How to read an SMS from Arduino and get LED to switch on or off

Tags: arduino, gsm

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
char inchar; //Will hold the incoming character from the serial port.
SoftwareSerial cell(2,3); //Create a 'fake' serial port. Pin 2 is the Rx pin, pin 3 is the Tx pin.

 int led1 = A2;

 void setup()
 {
     // Prepare the digital output pins
     pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);

     //Initialize GSM module serial port for communication.
     cell.begin(19200);
     delay(30000); // Give time for GSM module to register on network, etc.
     cell.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Set SMS mode to text
     delay(200);
     cell.println("AT+CNMI=3,3,0,0"); // Set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
     delay(200);
 }

 void loop() 
 {
     //If a character comes in from the cellular module...
     if(cell.available() >0)
     {
         delay(10);
         inchar=cell.read(); 
         if (inchar=='a')
         {
             delay(10);
             inchar=cell.read();
             if (inchar=='0')
             {
                 digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
             } 
             else if (inchar=='1')
             {
                 digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
             }
             delay(10);
             delay(10);
         }
         cell.println("AT+CMGD=1,4"); // Delete all SMS
     }
 }
```

This is the code for receiving SMSes from the cellular network. I am using the Arduino Gboard with SIM900. There is no error in the code, but the LED on the board doesn't switch on or off in response to an SMS.

Why?

Comment: Can you please add a question, with a question mark? It isn't clear exactly what your problem(s) is/are.  What exactly does "there is no error in code" mean?  Are you receiving SMS correctly?

Comment: No sir, i have no eroor in my code.

Comment: So is the LED on the board is lighting incorrectly?

Comment: No sir, i have no eroor in my code.  problem:, i want to jst led on or off from the cellular network(mobile) ...exactly jst sms to arduino like #a0, or #a1 as per my program there led is on or off , there is also no problem on uploading but led does not give a response....my programm is run till the initial level means when i define initially led low or led high but then logic not follow..........so can u tell me is there any baudrate prob.?? i use 19200 for cell begain... so plzz try to help me...thanxx

Comment: ya there is no blinking of led....only in starting define led as a low or high it can be show but then logic nt apply..so if u have any idea ...thn tell me plzz

Comment: I see one gigantic problem: `delay`. You should **never** use delay in place of reading back and parsing the responses you get from the modem. While I cannot guarantee from just reading your code here that this is exactly what is causing the problems you ask about, I absolutely can guarantee you that using delay will get you in some kind trouble. So do yourself and everyone else a favour and stop using delay like that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fully functional code for sending a command thru SMS using Arduino and GSM, it will also reply the state of the light.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GPRS(10, 11);
String textMessage;
String lampState;
const int relay = 12; //If you're using a relay to switch, if not reverse all HIGH and LOW on the code

void setup() {  
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay, HIGH); // The current state of the light is ON

  Serial.begin(9600); 
  GPRS.begin(9600);
  delay(5000);
  Serial.print("GPRS ready...\r\n");
  GPRS.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n"); 
  delay(1000);
  GPRS.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r\n");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop(){
  if(GPRS.available()>0){
    textMessage = GPRS.readString();
    Serial.print(textMessage);    
    delay(10);
  } 
  if(textMessage.indexOf("ON")>=0){ //If you sent "ON" the lights will turn on
    // Turn on relay and save current state
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    lampState = "ON";
    Serial.println("Lamp set to ON\r\n");  
    textMessage = "";
    GPRS.println("AT+CMGS=\"+631234567890\""); // RECEIVER: change the phone number here with international code
    delay(500);
    GPRS.print("Lamp was finally switched ON.\r");
    GPRS.write( 0x1a );
    delay(1000);
  }
  if(textMessage.indexOf("OFF")>=0){
    // Turn off relay and save current state
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
    lampState = "OFF"; 
    Serial.println("Lamp set to OFF\r\n");
    textMessage = "";
    GPRS.println("AT+CMGS=\"+631234567890\""); /// RECEIVER: change the phone number here with international code
    delay(500);
    GPRS.print("Lamp was finally switched OFF.\r");
    GPRS.write( 0x1a );
    delay(1000);
  }
  if(textMessage.indexOf("STATUS")>=0){
    String message = "Lamp is " + lampState;
    GPRS.print("AT+CMGF=1"); 
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Lamp state resquest");
    textMessage = "";
    GPRS.println("AT+CMGS=\"+631234567890\""); // RECEIVER: change the phone number here with international code
    delay(500);
    GPRS.print("Lamp is currently ");
    GPRS.println(lampState ? "ON" : "OFF"); // This is to show if the light is currently switched on or off
    GPRS.write( 0x1a );
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, `GPRS.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");` or `GPRS.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); ` why did you use **\n**, is that necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
AT+CNMI=3,3,0,0
```

to:

```
AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is the best way.

```
// if You use SoftwareSerial lib, declare object for GSM
SoftwareSerial gsm(8,9); // TX, RX
void setup(){
     // initialise UART and GSM communication between Arduino and modem
     Serial.begin(115200);
     gsm.begin(115200);
     // wait 5-10sec. for modem whitch must connect to the network
     delay(5000);
     // configure modem - remember! modem didn't remeber Your's configuration!
     gsm.print("at+cmgf=1\r"); // use full functionality (calls, sms, gprs) - see app note
     gsm.print("at+clip=1\r"); // enable presentation number
     gsm.print("at+cscs=\"GSM\"\r"); // configure sms as standard text messages
     gsm.print("at+cnmi=1,2,0,0,0\r"); // show received sms and store in sim (probobly, I don't compre this settings with app note but it's working :)
}
void loop(){
     String response = gsmAnswer();
    if(response.indexOf("+CMT:") > 0 ) { // SMS arrived
    // Now You can parse Your Message, if You wont controll only LED, just write
       if(response.indexOf("LED ON") > 0) {
          digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // enable it
       }else if(response.indexOf("LED OFF") > 0) {
          digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); // turn off
       }
       delay(1000);
    }
}


String gsmAnswer(){
   String answer;
   while(!gsm.available());
   while(gsm.available()){
     delay(5);
     if(Serial.available() > 0){
       char s = (char)gsm.read();
       answer += s;
     }
  }
  return answer;
}
```

One think more, incomming sms has the following format:

```
+CMT: "+48xxxxxxxxx","","17/07/07,21:57:04+08"
Test of arrived messages
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first know exactly what the response is before attempting to parse it.

Try something simple like the following code (note: untested!) to get a feeling of what you should look for:

```
void loop() {
    if(cell.available() > 0) {
        char ch = cell.read();
        Serial.print(ch);
    }
}
```

My guess is you'll see more than just a '0' or a '1' :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void loop() {
    while(cell.available() > 0) {inchar = cell.read(); readString+=c;delay(1);} ///can be a delay up to (10) so you can get a clear reading
    Serial.print(readString);  /// Declare a string    " String readString; "
    for (i=0; i<200; i++){  /// Serch for the txt you sent up to (200) times it depends how long your ""readString" is
      if(readString.substring(i,i+4)=="RING"){ //// I am looking for the word RING sent from my phone
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
        break;

      } 
    }   
}
```

this will help you find the specific word ir your reading (text message)